# how to give certain height over than given to scroll option for the text area using css and jquery

Tags: jquery, css, textarea, chat

We developing the chat application, In this application have text area. user entering text into text area i need show below requirement.

first i need to give some height for the text area or what ever default coming it enough. after entering in the text area auto increase the some certain height limit only.

More than the certain height text given user. need to give overflow-y: scroll.only.

after the text send and text area should be coming to the original position.

```html
<div style="background: #a61735;display: inline-flex; width: 100%;padding-left: 10px;padding-bottom: 2px;margin-bottom: 51px;">
  <div class="right" style="padding: 0px; margin-top: 0px; width: 100%;">
   <textarea autofocus="autofocus" id="txtarqlmchat" style="min-height: 50px;overflow-y: scroll;"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div style="padding-top: 0px;padding-left: 8px;margin-right: 17px;margin-top: 6px">
   <img src="img/send.png" width="40px">
  </div>
 
 </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have written code for `textbox`. Hope it will help you.

Html-

```
<div>
    <textarea autofocus="autofocus" id="txtarqlmchat" style="min-height: 50px;overflow-y: scroll;" data-limit='150'></textarea>
    <button class="resetHight">reset</button>
</div>
```

jQuery -

```
$('#txtarqlmchat').on('keydown',function(){
    var limitH = $(this).attr('data-limit');
    var innerH = $('#txtarqlmchat')[0].scrollHeight;
    if(innerH <= limitH){
       $('#txtarqlmchat').height(innerH);
    }
    else{
      $('#txtarqlmchat').height(limitH);
    }
})
$('.resetHight').on('click',function(){
    $('#txtarqlmchat').height(50);
})
```

In this `data-limit='150'` is the certain height that given. `resetHight` is button to reset textbox height.
Demo - [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhananjaymane11/s4k4q500/6/)

Comment: not working this. it's not fixed the height it's going on increasing

Comment: when key down is fixed the height and when i key up it is going to increasing the text area height looks like screen shot is comming

Comment: DJAy we need to write anything code when keydown time?

Comment: certain height scrolling comming in that time is key down screen 1 but when i key up certain height is increase it's showing like screen shot 2

Comment: no DJay, it working fine but when i keydown in that time textarea height is increasing.when key up coming good i ant same when key down also. i attached the screen shot please see